# Run requeriments.txt with pip install from Artifactory

Tags: python, pip, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a Jenkins Pipeline where I absorb a Python project from GitLab and the libraries have to be installed from [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) (not from web) while the pipeline create docker image. The image is created but without libraries because **I have no permissions in docker server to install *pip***, so **is it possible to run a Python Requeriments.txt from Artifactory (lodge pip in a repository or something)?**